# jquery .load dynamic image

Tags: jquery, load, captcha

Is there any way I can use the .load event(or any other jquery event) with a dynamic image such as this

Whenever I try to use the .load or .get method to reload that page into the document it just come out as ��������  in Firefox and �PNG  in internet explorer.

What am I missing here? What would be the best way to do this?

Overall what I'm trying to accomplish here is to reload the captcha.php file into a div when a link is clicked and have a different captcha image be shown without refreshing the page.

The problem can be found here
http://www.seewhosoutthere.com/createAccount

clicking on the little blue "refresh" button next to the captcha will give the result I'm talking about.

The code currently being used for that page is

```
$('a#refresh').click(function(){
    $('#captcha').load('captcha.php');
});
```

Comment: There's probably an encoding issue (wrong character set being used somewhere). Can you post the full HTML, etc.? Or a link. Does the PHP file work independently?

Comment: its working for me , is it on some browser??

Comment: So are you asking how to reload different captcha images without a full page reload?

Comment: I edited my main post to show a page where the problem exists. I threw back up the captcha so you all can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (which isn't intended for binary data...which is why you get those fun symbols with the encoding) you just need to create an `<img>` element with the right `src` and put it where you want in the document, for example:

```
$("<img />", { src:"http://www.seewhosoutthere.com/captcha"}).appendTo("#myDiv");
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hQ8y2/1/).

Comment: Hey nick, the problem with that is then it adds another captcha image(with the same security) to the same div so there are multiple images.

Comment: @Ryan - Oh if you want to replace it, just do `$('#myDiv').html($("<img />", { src:"http://www.seewhosoutthere.com/captcha"}));`, or call `$('#myDiv').empty()` before...whichever :)

Comment: But that still only loads the identical captcha image, the image is not refreshed with a new code.

Comment: @Ryan - if you want to load a new one you need to put a cache breaker on the URL, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hQ8y2/2/

Comment: interesting. I've never heard of a thing like that. I'll have to do some research on that. Thanks much sir, that solved my problem.