# Wait for image full load on ajax action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

On my page there is `ajax` action, which loads `div`, that contain image on left and text on right.

The problem: first of all text loads, and on the left (it aligned left), then image loads, text shifts on right, and that looks really not smooth.

I tried something like :

```
$('div#to_load').ready(function() {
    $('div#to_load').fadeIn();
});
```

but that doesn't help.

What can I do?

Comment: You do know you're missing some quotes in your code?

Comment: Only the document has a ready method.

Comment: @Patrick, I just write it here, it is not part of my code

Comment: same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384286/jquery-dynamically-download-image-ie-doesnt-know-its-width-and-its-height

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I think you have to try this trick found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362820/jquery-load-dynamic-image) :

```
$("<img />", { src:"thelinkofyourimage"}).appendTo("div#to_load").fadeOut(0).fadeIn(1000);
```

Have a look to this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qYHCn/.

Comment: Did you read the documentation you're linking to? It says "Load data from the server ..." ?

Comment: How would fading in an image solve the issue with the text being shifted once the image loads ?

Comment: I will explain better my answer.

Comment: @adeneo I think there are rudeless way to tell people that are doing something wrong.

Comment: @LucasWillems The idea is right, but ain't gonna work, paste this in your console here (your loading binary data into a div) : ``$("#answer-17761449").load("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fd2eaacae1fcf0fdf7956df4ea15cdab?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG")``

Comment: @adeneo do you have a suggestion regards the handling of the problem?

Comment: @LucasWillems: Is your new solution waits for image loading? I think NO

Comment: @steo - when was I being rude, I asked two legitimate questions as the answer got two upvotes and wasn't even close to solving the issue ?

Comment: And this still isn't an answer, if the text shifts once the images are inserted, fading it in won't make a difference. Now the text will shift, an empty space will appear, and an image will fade in, not much better ?

Comment: @LucasWillems, actually your answer in first edit was absolutely correct. It works for me ( i mean using load with callback)

Answer (score 0):

You could track when all the images have loaded like so

```
var element = $('div#to_load');
var images = element.find('img');
var count = images.length;

for( var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   $(images[i]).load(function(){
     count--;
     if( count === 0 ){
        element.fadeIn();
     }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to load image and text separately, not at once.

And for the shifting problem put image inside another div and define the size when it loads. Then text can't come to image space since we already giving space for image div.

sample code

```
$('#ImageID')
 .load(
      function(){
           //Do stuff once the image specified above is loaded
           $('#textId').html('your text');
      }
 );
```

Comment: How do you load text?

Comment: Would that not be wasting time?

Comment: If so you can load text seperatly, but we need to define the size of image div.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want content to shift, you must declare the size the image will take up so that the required space is already accounted for when the browser does it's render.

Make sure you declare the size of the image, or the size of the container before you load

```
<div id="to_load">
    <img src="...." height="400" width="400" />
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="to_load" style="height:400px;width:400px;overflow:hidden">
    ..dynamic content
</div>
```

Declaring image size either on the img element or in your stylesheet is a best practice recommendation anyways

[Reflows & Repaint](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/)

---

Maybe you'd like something like this

```
#to_load {
    width: 523px;
    height: 192px;
}
#to_load img {
    display: none;
}

setTimeout(function() {
    $("<img />", { src:"http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/jquery_logo.png"})
        .on('load', function(){
            $(this).appendTo("#to_load").fadeIn(500);
        });
},1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AWntU/

Answer (score 0):

You could smoothly animate it in with jQuery (handy anyway when you are doing your ajax requests with jQuery):

jQuery

```
$("body").prepend('<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img">');
$("img").animate({
    opacity: 1,
    left: 0
}, 700);
```

CSS

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.8em ; 
    left: -300px;
    position: relative;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rttw/).